# How do i call an API using php curl correctly? I am getting http status code of 401

Tags: php, curl, postman

I am trying to call an API (using bearer token authorization) in php curl but i am getting a response 401.

I have tried using the code from post man but i got a different error with that. I have included the the code. The Curl is the first function. I have a different API to get the bearer token and that works fine but when i pass the bearer token to my php Curl request i get http status code of 401

```
function restRequestDispute($method, $endpoint, $data, $content_type, $token) 
{

            $ch = curl_init($endpoint);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
                        array("Authorization: Bearer " . $token,
                            "Content-type: $content_type", 
                              "Accepts: application/json"));
                             // 'Content-Length: 0'));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
            $method = strtoupper($method);

            switch ($method) {
                case "GET":
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
                    break;
                case "DELETE":
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
                    break;
                case "PUT":
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
                case "POST":
                //return $data;
                    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("Error: Invalid HTTP method '$method' $endpoint");
                    return null;
            }

            $oRet = new StdClass;
            $oRet->response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

            $oRet->status   = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $oRet;

}

function createDispute()
{
    try{
    $local_date = $date;
    $method ="POST";
    $content_type="application/json";

    $accessToken  = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoiU2hlcmlmZi5PcGVsIiwiZXhwIjoxNTU0MzE2ODAzLCJpc3MiOiJ1cC1uZy5jb20iLCJhdWQiOiJ1cC1uZy5jb20ifQ.8LN6gcoDEpb2i8h9NA0Z_PNxRLweaHh44PN5nbfER10";
    $params = array (
        "issuerrrn"=> "003409137690",
        "transactionamount"=> "-7100",
        "localtransactiondate"=> "20181210",
        "logcomment"=> "comment",
        "amountdispenced"=>"0",
        "currentstatus"=> "NotStarted",
        "transitionaction"=> "GoodsServicesNotReceived"

        );

    $endpoint="https://172.**.*.***:***/api/DisputeWIthIssRrn?issuerrrn=003409137690&transactionamount=-7100&localtransactiondate=20181210&logcomment=comment&amountdispenced=0&currentstatus=NotStarted&transitionaction=GoodsServicesNotReceived";       

    $response = restRequestDispute($method, $endpoint, "", $content_type, $accessToken);

    return $response;
    } catch(Exception $e){

        $returned_result  =  ["error" => ["status" => "Exception", "data" => $e->getMessage()]];
        return $returned_result;

    }   

}
```

Comment: `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` - acceptable values do not include `false` - my advice, use `2` instead

Comment: @RamRaider Actually in this situation `false` is converted to `0` and it's accepted value: `0 to not check the names`

Comment: granted false equates to zero but that opens the possibility of mitm attacks and should be ignored for that reason alone perhaps

Comment: You are using `POST` but You are sending the params in Your url. Try to replace the `""` by $params.

Answer (score 1):

I had a little tinker with your curl function, moved some things about a little and added in a couple of things - one thing is the enhanced debugging information in the output and the other is the use of `cainfo` in the SSL options. Hope it helps

```
function restRequestDispute($method, $endpoint, $data, $content_type, $token){
    try{

        /* you can freely download cacert.pem from the internet - always use when performing SSL communications in cURL */
        $cacert = '/path/to/your/cacert.pem';
        /* add additional debug info to this stream */
        $vbh = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');


        $method = strtoupper( $method );

        $ch = curl_init( $endpoint );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
                    array(
                        "Authorization: Bearer " . $token,
                        "Content-type: $content_type",
                        "Accepts: application/json"
                        )
                    );


        if( parse_url( $endpoint,PHP_URL_SCHEME )=='https' ){
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cacert );
        }

        /* set the options for enhanced debugging */
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $vbh );

        switch( $method ) {
            case "GET":
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true );
            break;
            case "DELETE":
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE" );
            break;
            case "PUT":
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT" );
            break;
            case "POST":
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
            break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Error: Invalid HTTP method '$method' $endpoint");
                return null;
        }

        $oRet = new StdClass;
        $oRet->response = json_decode( curl_exec( $ch ) );
        $oRet->status   = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $oRet->errors   = curl_error( $ch );

        /* add verbose information to the output for enhanced debugging */
        rewind( $vbh );
        $oRet->verbose = stream_get_contents( $vbh );
        fclose( $vbh );

        curl_close( $ch );
        return $oRet;

    }catch( Exception $e ){
        exit( $e->getMessage() );
    }
}
```

When the function returns if you examine the output of `$oRet->verbose` or, as called, `$response->verbose` you should see more info which has helped me many times resolve problems with curl requests.

Looking at how you call the above function I notice this:

```
`restRequestDispute( $method, $endpoint, "", $content_type, $accessToken );`
```

should that not instead be

```
`restRequestDispute( $method, $endpoint, $params, $content_type, $accessToken );`
```

Comment: Thank you RamRaider. I tried it but did not work. I notice that  I get the 401 error on post one if i call the create dispute api without calling the token api but once i call the token api on postman the create dispute api works even though i did not specify the authorization type or pass the bearer token. How does post man send the authorization. Is there some sort of data that is being passed in the header?

Comment: What endpoint do you use? The one in the question with the querystring or simply `https://172.**.*.***:***/api/DisputeWIthIssRrn`?

Comment: I am using the one in the question

Comment: I'd suggest that you use simply the base url without the querystring, download a valid `cacert.pem`, perhaps add a `USERAGENT` option to the curl request and try like that - without knowing the endpoint url or any verbose information returned it is hard to know. Have you looked at the verbose information?

Comment: yes i have looked into the verbose information - "< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue < HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized < Content-Length: 0 < Server: Kestrel < WWW-Authenticate: Bearer < X-Powered-By: ASP.NET < Date: Fri, 05 Apr 2019 16:36:52 GMT * HTTP error before end of send, stop sending < * Closing connection 2 )"